# Nuxtjs and Scatum duplicate requests and no cookie stored

Tags: laravel, cookies, nuxt.js

I am facing a weird problem. I have a Laravel API server setup and a Nuxtjs frontend. I am using `LaravelSanctum` Provider in Nuxtjs. I am able to send request and the authentication and data retrival is fine. However, the cookies doesn't seem to get stored in my local storage.

`login.vue`

```html
<script>
export default {
  async login() {
    this.$auth.loginWith('laravelSanctum', {
      data: {
        email: 'test@gmail.com',
        password: 'test',
      },
    })
  },
}
</script>
```

`nuxt.config.js`

```js
axios: {
  baseURL: 'http://local.api.test/api/v1/',
  proxy: true,
  credentials: true,
},

proxy: {
  '/laravel': {
    target: 'http://local.api.test/api/v1/',
    pathRewrite: { '^/laravel': '/' },
  },
},

auth: {
  strategies: {
    laravelSanctum: {
      provider: 'laravel/sanctum',
      url: 'http://local.api.test',
      endpoints: {
        login: {
          url: '/api/v1/login/admin',
        },
        user: {
          url: '/api/v1/admin',
        },
      },
    },
  },
},
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image: No cookies stored]

Comment: Some actual code as text with your configuration or/and your template + script would be quite helpful here. Are you using the `setUser` method after the `login` one?

Comment: You should have an `await` in front of `this.$auth.loginWith`. And my last part of my previous comment is still valid.